# App crashes in release build cause of QuickBlox

Tags: android, apk, release, quickblox

Im using quickblox in my application and my current sdk version is the latest one in debug mode everything runs smoothly but when i sign my application for the release build i have noticed that i need to add some configuration in the progaurd for quickblox and some other libraries so the apk was revealed but when i run it it crashes when trying to login through quickblox giving me this

```
enter code here
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.a.b.e.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.a.b.a.b.h.<init>(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.a.b.a.b.b.<init>(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.a.b.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.quickblox.core.rest.RestRequest.a(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.quickblox.core.rest.RestRequest.asyncRequestWithCallback(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.a(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.performAsyncWithCallback(Unknown Source)
10-06 16:36:48.469 8143-8143/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.quickblox.auth.QBAuth.createSessionUsingSocialProvider(Unknown Source)
```

can someone please help me in that what I'm missing is there a way to make it run in the release apk.
Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my mistake in my pro file i did -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
and didnt add -keep class org.apache.http.**{ public *;}
my fault hope it helps anyone who face it

Answer (score 0):

When issue exist in release apk, then maximum chances for issue because of proguard.
So add below line in your project:

```
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```